# Union of two sorted arrays in python

Tags: python

When I run this code in geeks for geeks practice code it shows me error, but when I run this in jupyter notebook it runs correctly

```py
class Solution:
    def merge_arrays(self, a, b, n, m):
        a = set(a)
        b = set(b)
        return a.union(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases = int(input())
    for cases in range(test_cases):
        n, m = map(int, input().strip().split())
        a = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        b = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        ob = Solution()
        li = ob.merge_arrays(a, b, n, m)
        for val in li:
            print(val, end="")
        print()
```

Data is:

```
n = 2

a = [1, 35]

m = 8

b = [1, 6, 9, 13, 15, 20, 25, 29, 46]
```

Code is:

```
def merge_arrays(self, a, b, n, m):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return a.union(b)
```

Comment: Please share code as text, not image.

Comment: Please add to your question's post text of an error that Geek-for-Geek shows you.

Comment: Also please put a link into your question's post to geek-for-geek problem description page, so that we know details about your task.

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow inserted HTML (`<br>`) into Python. Remove those bits.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant that the issue had been resolved. Please post the error as formatted text in your original post, listing the appropriate inputs and expected output. Your screenshot is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you run this:

```py
    n = 2
    a = [1, 35]
    m = 8
    b = [1, 6, 9, 13, 15, 20, 25, 29, 46]
    solution = Solution().merge_arrays(a, b, n, m)
    print(solution)
```

You get: `{1, 35, 6, 9, 13, 46, 15, 20, 25, 29}`. This is a `set`, not a `list`.
And this is not preserving the order of items.

If you want to preserve items order, you need to code `merge_arrays` a different way.

If you want to keep insertion order, you can use the `dict.fromkeys` trick:

```py
ordered = dict.fromkeys  # or collections.OrderedDict


class Solution:
    def merge_arrays(self, a, b, n, m):
        a = ordered(a)
        b = ordered(b)
        a.update(b)
        return list(a)
```

That way, you get: `[1, 35, 6, 9, 13, 15, 20, 25, 29, 46]`.

**Edit**

If you want a sorted list you can use the following solution:

```py
a = set(a)
b = set(b)
return list(sorted(a | b))
```

Comment: but i want a sorted list or array at the end

Comment: You can use the `sorted` function. See my edit.